# CallbackOnCollectedDelegate was detected in static class

Tags: c#

This is a Wave class which is available on many sites. i used this class in one of my projects and it's running on +20 computers for debugging.
Every thing is good but some times the program stops working when user injects big tasks to it and then crash will accrue in above class.

i studied many similar questions on internet and also all similar posts on this site. most of times there is same problem in these cases, but i couldn't solve it.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
namespace SoundViewer
{
public enum WaveFormats
{
    Pcm = 1,
    Float = 3
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public class WaveFormat
{
    public short wFormatTag;
    public short nChannels;
    public int nSamplesPerSec;
    public int nAvgBytesPerSec;
    public short nBlockAlign;
    public short wBitsPerSample;
    public short cbSize;

    public WaveFormat(int rate, int bits, int channels)
    {
        wFormatTag = (short)WaveFormats.Pcm;
        nChannels = (short)channels;
        nSamplesPerSec = rate;
        wBitsPerSample = (short)bits;
        cbSize = 0;

        nBlockAlign = (short)(channels * (bits / 8));
        nAvgBytesPerSec = nSamplesPerSec * nBlockAlign;
    }
}

internal class WaveNative
{
    // consts
    public const int MMSYSERR_NOERROR = 0; // no error

    public const int MM_WOM_OPEN = 0x3BB;
    public const int MM_WOM_CLOSE = 0x3BC;
    public const int MM_WOM_DONE = 0x3BD;

    public const int MM_WIM_OPEN = 0x3BE;
    public const int MM_WIM_CLOSE = 0x3BF;
    public const int MM_WIM_DATA = 0x3C0;

    public const int CALLBACK_FUNCTION = 0x00030000;    // dwCallback is a FARPROC 

    public const int TIME_MS = 0x0001;  // time in milliseconds 
    public const int TIME_SAMPLES = 0x0002;  // number of wave samples 
    public const int TIME_BYTES = 0x0004;  // current byte offset 

    // callbacks
    public delegate void WaveDelegate(IntPtr hdrvr, int uMsg, int dwUser, ref WaveHdr wavhdr, int dwParam2);

    // structs 

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct WaveHdr
    {
        public IntPtr lpData; // pointer to locked data buffer
        public int dwBufferLength; // length of data buffer
        public int dwBytesRecorded; // used for input only
        public IntPtr dwUser; // for client's use
        public int dwFlags; // assorted flags (see defines)
        public int dwLoops; // loop control counter
        public IntPtr lpNext; // PWaveHdr, reserved for driver
        public int reserved; // reserved for driver
    }

    private const string mmdll = "winmm.dll";

    // WaveOut calls
    [DllImport(mmdll)]
    public static extern int waveOutGetNumDevs();
    [DllImport(mmdll)]
    public static extern int waveOutPrepareHeader(IntPtr hWaveOut, ref WaveHdr lpWaveOutHdr, int uSize);
    [DllImport(mmdll)]
    public static extern int waveOutUnprepareHeader(IntPtr hWaveOut, ref WaveHdr lpWaveOutHdr, int uSize);
    [DllImport(mmdll)]
    public static extern int waveOutWrite(IntPtr hWaveOut, ref WaveHdr lpWaveOutHdr, int uSize);
    [DllImport(mmdll)]
    public static extern int waveOutOpen(out IntPtr hWaveOut, int uDeviceID, WaveFormat lpFormat, WaveDelegate dwCallback, int dwInstance, int dwFlags);
    [DllImport(mmdll)]
    public static extern int waveOutReset(IntPtr hWaveOut);
    [DllImport(mmdll)]
    public static extern int waveOutClose(IntPtr hWaveOut);
    [DllImport(mmdll)]
    public static extern int waveOutPause(IntPtr hWaveOut);
    [DllImport(mmdll)]
    public static extern int waveOutRestart(IntPtr hWaveOut);
    [DllImport(mmdll)]
    public static extern int waveOutGetPosition(IntPtr hWaveOut, out int lpInfo, int uSize);
    [DllImport(mmdll)]
    public static extern int waveOutSetVolume(IntPtr hWaveOut, int dwVolume);
    [DllImport(mmdll)]
    public static extern int waveOutGetVolume(IntPtr hWaveOut, out int dwVolume);

    // WaveIn calls
    [DllImport(mmdll)]
    public static extern int waveInGetNumDevs();
    [DllImport(mmdll)]
    public static extern int waveInAddBuffer(IntPtr hwi, ref WaveHdr pwh, int cbwh);
    [DllImport(mmdll)]
    public static extern int waveInClose(IntPtr hwi);
    [DllImport(mmdll)]
    public static extern int waveInOpen(out IntPtr phwi, int uDeviceID, WaveFormat lpFormat, WaveDelegate dwCallback, int dwInstance, int dwFlags);
    [DllImport(mmdll)]
    public static extern int waveInPrepareHeader(IntPtr hWaveIn, ref WaveHdr lpWaveInHdr, int uSize);
    [DllImport(mmdll)]
    public static extern int waveInUnprepareHeader(IntPtr hWaveIn, ref WaveHdr lpWaveInHdr, int uSize);
    [DllImport(mmdll)]
    public static extern int waveInReset(IntPtr hwi);
    [DllImport(mmdll)]
    public static extern int waveInStart(IntPtr hwi);
    [DllImport(mmdll)]
    public static extern int waveInStop(IntPtr hwi);
}
}
```

members of the above name space used several times separate forms.

The Error:
*A callback was made on a garbage collected of type 'SoundProcessing! SoundViewer.WaveNative+WaveDelegate::Invoke'. This may cause application crashes, corruption and data loss. when passing delegates to unmanaged code, they must be kept alive by the managed application until it is guaranteed that they will never be called.*

it seems the problem is on delegate call back  (//call back Line) and the solution is to keep it alive, but how?!
Is it the best solution? What about other solutions?
Thanks.

Complete Source of program is available on many sites include of the below link
http://www.4shared.com/folder/WoM9Hkzp/SourceSample.html

Comment: It is a *very* common bug when you pinvoke a function that registers a callback.  The GC cannot see that the native code is holding a reference to the delegate object, you must store it in a static variable or use GCHandle.Alloc() to ensure it does.  This api is already ably wrapped in the NAudio library btw.